# Java Threads and high cpu usage

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, cpu-usage

I've done some search here and couldn't find an answer, so I think it's better to ask.
I'm running a little bit expensive algorithm in a simple Java swing application. Let me describe the structure:

In my `JPanel` `run()` method:

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        Algorithm alg = new Algorithm(signal);
        new Thread(alg).start();

        //Wait for algorithm to finish 
        signal.await(alg);

        updateInterface();

        Thread.sleep(60L);
    }
}
```

Algorithm loops through the pixels of a .JPG file, then loops through another large Integer array (length ~ 12000) and returns. There are very no extra expensive calculationslot. I call `Thread.sleep(60L)` in the Algorithm `run()` method also.

The `udpateInterface()` method is very fast, just draw some `java.awt.Polygon` objects.

Even though I'm calling `Thread.sleep(60L)`, the CPU usage is about 160% on my Mac Book (2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, Mem 4GB 1067).

Is there a way I can run this without melting my computer? I'm using `CountDownLatch` as
a wait notify mechanism.

Thanks!

Comment: `Thread.sleep` is affecting the parent thread (the one with the `while` shown), not the *new* thread (`new Thread`)... the code might actually be spawning multiple threads at once, depending upon `signal` and all.

Comment: Yes, but the Algorithm thread also has a sleep call.

Comment: I don't understand what the purpose of the `sleep` call is. If you have work to be done, why are you sleeping"? What do you mean "melting my computer?! Work can't melt your computer. The purpose of the computer is to do work. If you have useful work to be done, make the CPUs do it. That's what they're for.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh, *you've* never had a computer melt? Lucky :) Usually it involves user error such as lack of a properly functioning heatsink *rolls eyes*

Comment: @pst: Computers melt due to hardware problems, not computing load.

Comment: @pst: In other words, their capability is wasted. The top of the envelope is there so they can do lots of work very fast. If you're inefficient or wasting CPU, that's one thing. But if you have useful work to do, you want the CPU to do it as quickly as possible.

Comment: If you are concerned about CPU load you should figure out what is causing the high load. It looks like it's your algorithm. So what do you want to do about that? Not run it?

Comment: unrelated, just a beware: all interaction with a Swing ui _must_ happen on the EDT (which may or may not be the case in yours, no way to tell from the snippet :-)

Comment: @kleopatra While it's wise to default to the assumption that your Swing UI interactions should happen on the EDT, it's not totally true anymore.  There are some specific Swing UI interactions that are thread safe.  If choosing to do so from a thread, make sure to read the docs carefully for limitations though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the following pattern to schedule a repeating task.

```
private ScheduledExecutorService executorService = null;

public void start() {
    if (executorService != null && !executorService.isShutdown()) return;

    executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Algorithm alg = new Algorithm(signal);
                alg.run();
                updateInterface();
            }
        }, 0, 60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public void stop() {
    if (executorService != null)
        executorService.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

160% CPU usage is relative to a *single* core of your machine -- that is, the maximum possible on your machine is 200%, because it has two cores.  You're not melting your processor.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sometimes it get's very close to 200%, i dont know if this will damage the computer...

Comment: No.  This is perfectly normal -- in fact, 200% usage is a _good_ sign that your application is parallelizing the work effectively.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Or wasting energy effectively ;-) Keeping the CPUs busy isn't quite the same as keeping them productive... in any case, I concur that the CPUs have *something* to do, which isn't necessarily bad. However, the question remains: How to make them "work less" (take longer) while solving this?

Comment: Unless there is something very wrong with the computer, you can't damage it by giving it computing work to do.

Comment: @pst: Quite the reverse, you are much more likely to annoy the user and look incompetent when his $1,000 CPU is less than fully used while he's *waiting* for your program to do the work he asked it to do.

Comment: @pst: A user saying "I really wish my CPU was more idle" is about as common as lawyer saying "I'm so glad my client talked to the police". It just doesn't happen. If there's work to be done, you want your computer to do it.

Comment: My concern is the the temperature. I'm sure it's not a good ideia to run a program four 8-10 hours, with the cpu temperature at the maximum. I turns it into a barbecue machine.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about that.  I promise.  If your computer is warming up, it will force the CPU to slow down, if necessary.

Comment: It takes _much_ more effort than this to cause a computer to overheat to the point of causing damage.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point starting another thread if all you're going to do afterward is make the current thread wait for the other one to finish.  You might as well just run the algorithm in the thread you already have; either way, you won't proceeed to `updateInterface()` until the algorithm is done.

As others have pointed out, after the algorithm finishes and you update the UI, you're only waiting 60 milliseconds before starting the algorithm again.  It sounds like your program is spending most of its time running the algorithm.  That's fine if you need it to update the screen that quickly, but you might consider using a longer delay otherwise.

Also, you're starting a new thread each time through the loop.  Does that thread run the algorithm once and then terminate, or does it run the algorithm in a loop?  If you have a loop starting threads that are each long-running CPU-intensive loops, you might be accidentally running many copies of the algorithm at once.  If you expect the algorithm thread to terminate after it signals you, you should `join()` it to make sure.

Comment: The Thread runs the algorithm and finishes. I already tried to run in the same Thread, and it increases the cpu usage. The synchronization is OK, what i need is to redesign this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How much wait do you want? If you want to wait for 60 seconds, you should use 60000L, as the time is specified in milliseconds.